# How can I add PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) to the Date&Time panel

Tags: indicator

I would like to add PDT to the list of locations in the Date & Time panel. [image]

I have UTC, so I think that in general, abstract locations are working. But when trying to add PDT, I only get this unresponsive stop-icon. 
[image]

SO: is there a way to add PDT to the list?

Comment: This is likely a feature request, for the 'Time & Date' applet.

Comment: Features can be requested [with a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), or by [submitting an idea on Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Only UTC is supported as an abstract 'Location'.

If your city uses PDT, typing in the name of your city should give it as a suggestion, and the time will be adjusted properly to include Daylight savings effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably specify a city like Los Angeles, and it will give you the time in PDT.

Comment: thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. I actually want PDT, not a city. The reason was the UDS, where the schedules were given in 'PDT'. So I wanted to look at my clock and see 'PDT'. The schedules did (rightfully) not say: "Oakland time" although PDT is used in Oakland. And I wanted the same for my clock.